# Java: Counter Indentation

Tags: java

I am very new to java and trying to create a java app which (when ran inside a terminal) will copy what text is inside and if there is a curly { bracket then add 3 spaces, when there is a curly } bracket then remove 3 spaces. There should be a counter to indent another 3 spaces each time a { appears *(see example)*

**Example:**
*File1.txt*:

```
Hello{StackOverflow}{Users}
```

The output should be *File2.txt*:

```
Hello
{
   StackOverflow
}

{
      Users
}
```

What I currently get outputed to *File2.txt* is:

```
Hello
{
   StackOverflow
}

{
   Users
```

I am missing my last bracket (how do I fix this?) and don't know how to loop my indentation based on the counter. Please help

My current code:

```
import java.io;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myapp {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

        File InputFile = new File(argv[0]);
        Scanner FileScanner = new Scanner(InputFile);
        FileWriter Writer = new FileWriter(argv[1]);
        BufferedWriter OutputWriter = new BufferedWriter(Writer);

        while (FileScanner.hasNextLine() == true) {
            String a = FileScanner.nextLine();

            try {
                int indent = 0;
                {

                    if (a.contains("{")) {
                        indent++;

                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {

                        OutputWriter.write("   ");
                    }
                    OutputWriter.write(a);
                }

                if (a.contains("}")) {
                    indent--;

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
            }
            OutputWriter.write("}");
        }
    }
}
```

p.s in Terminal (to run/test) I use the following command:

```
$java myapp File1.txt File2.txt
```

Thank you :)

Comment: How is it s in :OutputWriter.write(s);?

Comment: Please indent your own code properly first! I'm not able to reead it in the state that it's currently in. If you're using any IDE, it will probably have some sort of auto-indenting feature that you can use. If not, you can use a bunch of sites online to indent your code properly. The harder it is to read, the harder it will be to debug.

Comment: Sorry I changed it to OutputWriter.write(a) :P

Comment: I will re-indent and update now

Comment: That's not the code that accounts for the output you posted. It reads the first line (the only one) and then print it back, while the output shows multiple lines and spaces

Comment: That's strange Piyin :/ I run that script (only that code) and it gives me that output...I don't know where else the code could be coming from

Comment: How would I read all lines? Maybe that is my issue :L

Comment: That code definitely does not output what you say it does. I get the first line output right back into the second file with some spaces at the beginning. I had to add OutputWriter.close() to make it do that.

Comment: Does your input file as you write it here ? `Hello{StackOverflow}{Users}`
I

Comment: @Piyin it has a while loop to read all the lines; though you're right that the code will not produce the output shown from the input shown

Comment: @Terry24421 You are reading all lines, but there's only one in the input, so you're only reading one. Then your code is printing it back. I would help you, but I won't until you post the real code, or the real output, so I could be certain what the problem is

Comment: @dsh I didn't say it wasn't. I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear, though

Comment: I agree with @Piyin, I run the code and the output is not what you say. Add the real code or the real output.

Comment: I created a text document called "File1.txt" and it has "Hello{StackOverflow}{Users}" in line 1...its the real code and real output for me :/ I don't run any other scripts/code (im being genuine)

Comment: With both answers I get the same output :/ I am beginning to doubt what other script/code is interphering (as I am not using anything else...only myapp.java and myapp.class)

Comment: @Piyin oh, right, I read your comment as saying it would read only the first line of an input file; my mistake, you were just adding comment that his file has only one line.

Comment: @Terry24421 Ok, then you're probably editing a different source and trying out a different program. Please erase the generated program and make sure your call to it doesn't work. Then recompile and try it again.

Comment: @dsh No problem, I probably should choose better words

Answer (score 0):

Try closing `OutputWriter` at the end of the method via `OutputWriter.close()`.  It will flush the stream which is likely the cause of the missing `}`.

As far as your indentation issue, declare and initialize the `indent` counter outside the loop.  Otherwise, it will get reset to 0 with each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for an answer :) sadly it doesn't seem to work :( same output

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's ok I add the `finally` block.`

```
        finally{
            OutputWriter.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 File InputFile = new File(argv[0]);
 Scanner FileScanner = new Scanner(InputFile);
 FileWriter Writer = new FileWriter(argv[1]);
 BufferedWriter OutputWriter = new BufferedWriter(Writer);
 while (FileScanner.hasNextLine() == true) {
  String a = FileScanner.nextLine();
  String b = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
   if (a.charAt(i) == '{') {
     b += "\n{\n   ";
   } else if (a.charAt(i) == '}') {
     b += "\n}\n";
   } else {
     b += a.charAt(i);
   }
}
OutputWriter.write(b);
OutputWriter.close();
}}}
```